# how can i limit the X axis length when i have more labels in react-charts2.js?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

my environment: React with React-charts2

I want to limit the labels number when i have more labels, example: 1 year total range

This screen is that the date length is thirty days, and the limit rule is that three days are replaced by one field, how can i achieve?

my other charts rules is:

```js
const tickIntervalRule = () => {
        let tick;
        switch (true) {
          case dateDistance < 16:
            tick = 1; // will default value
            break;
          case 16 <= dateDistance && dateDistance <= 30:
            tick = 3; // 30/3 reutrn 10 labels
            break;
          case 31 <= dateDistance && dateDistance <= 90:
            tick = 10; // 90/10 reutrn 9 labels
            break;
          case 91 <= dateDistance && dateDistance <= 365:
            tick = 30; // 365/30 reutrn 12 labels
            break;
          case dateDistance > 365:
            tick = 60; // 365/60 reutrn 6 labels
            break;
          default:
        }
        return tick;
      };
```

expected look screen shot:
[30days dateRange in charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZn0R.jpg)

Comment: more likely this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925431/chartjs-draw-chart-with-label-by-month-data-by-day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChartJS - Draw chart with label by month, data by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925431/chartjs-draw-chart-with-label-by-month-data-by-day)